# logging stderr output when the error is that the stdout output file does not exist?

Tags: bash

I'm writing a very simple bash script that concats two files together and saving output into a log file

```
#!/bin/bash

file1="/srv/users/test/foo.txt"
file2="/srv/users/test/bar.txt"
newFile="/srv/users/test/foobar.txt"
logFile="/srv/users/test/log.txt"

echo "making file" >> $logFile
echo `date` >> $logFile

cat $file1 $file2 > $newFile 2>> $logFile

echo "finished making file" >> $logFile
```

But the problem is that if `newFile` does not exist, then an error is printed to the display rather than to the log file.

How can I make it so the error is printed to the log file instead of the display?

Thanks!

Comment: "echo \`date\` >> $logFile" ? Just `date >> $logfile`.. `then an error is printed` Please post the exact error message. If `newfile` does not exists, the `>` should create it, unless the directory does not exists.

Comment: @KamilCuk yes the directory also did not exist. Here's the error: `/usr/bin/combineCerts: line 11: /absolute/path/foobar.txt: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect the whole shell stderr instead of one command. Like:

```
{
   stuff
} 2>>"$logfile"

{ cat $file1 $file2 > $newFile; } 2>> $logFile
```

check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net

Comment: Ok I was trying to use \` chars when I should have beening using { and }. Thanks!

Comment: This worked and was just what I needed. I also learned that the space before and after the curly bracket, and the semi colon, where required

Comment: The space between `;` and `}` is not needed.. :p